# Ansible "parted" module failing to create partition in the first run. But, works fine in the second run. Is there something wrong?

Tags: ansible

```
  parted:
    device: /dev/vdb
    number: 1
    state: present
    flags:
      - lvm
```

Debug Outputs:

First Run:
In first run, partition output seems empty []

'''
changed: [Server1] => {
"changed": true,
"disk": {
"dev": "/dev/vdb",
"logical_block": 512,
"model": "Virtio Block Device",
"physical_block": 512,
"size": 524288000.0,
"table": "msdos",
"unit": "kib"
},
"invocation": {
"module_args": {
"align": "optimal",
"device": "/dev/vdb",
"flags": [
"lvm"
],
"label": "msdos",
"name": null,
"number": 1,
"part_end": "100%",
"part_start": "0%",
"part_type": "primary",
"state": "present",
"unit": "KiB"
}
},
"**partitions**": [],
"script": "unit KiB mklabel msdos"
}
'''

Second Run:
In second run, partition output has the partition info and the partition was also successful.

'''
changed: [Server1] => {
"changed": true,
"disk": {
"dev": "/dev/vdb",
"logical_block": 512,
"model": "Virtio Block Device",
"physical_block": 512,
"size": 524288000.0,
"table": "msdos",
"unit": "kib"
},
"invocation": {
"module_args": {
"align": "optimal",
"device": "/dev/vdb",
"flags": [
"lvm"
],
"label": "msdos",
"name": null,
"number": 1,
"part_end": "100%",
"part_start": "0%",
"part_type": "primary",
"state": "present",
"unit": "KiB"
}
},
"**partitions**": [
{
"begin": 1024.0,
"end": 524288000.0,
"flags": [
"lvm"
],
"fstype": "",
"name": "",
"num": 1,
"size": 524286976.0,
"unit": "kib"
}
],
"script": "unit KiB mkpart primary 0% 100% unit KiB set 1 lvm on"
}

'''

Also fdisk -l showed these info on different runs:

Without Partition:

```
Disk /dev/vdb: 500 GiB, 536870912000 bytes, 1048576000 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

First Run:

```
Disk /dev/vdb: 500 GiB, 536870912000 bytes, 1048576000 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x6b877516
```

Second Run:

```
Disk /dev/vdb: 500 GiB, 536870912000 bytes, 1048576000 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x6b877516

Device     Boot Start        End    Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/vdb1        2048 1048575999 1048573952  500G 8e Linux LVM
```

Comment: Please don't post textual content as screenshots; it impairs searching, is hard to read, and is explicitly mentioned in the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page. While editing your question to fix that, also include explanatory text why you think it "failed"

Comment: @mdaniel Thank you for your comment.
pasted debug output as text. Please look at the partition output of debug.

Comment: Aside from the output difference, does it not, in fact, create the partition the first time? "the map^W logs is not the terrain"

Comment: Yeah I came to this conclusion after partition was not done in the first run. Because next tasks threw the error "device /dev/vdb1 not found". When I checked into the node, there was no vdb1, just the vdb alone.

Comment: Also added some debug output on the question, thank you!

Comment: Hmm, that does seem pretty bad; I'm guessing you'll have to [open an issue](https://github.com/ansible-collections/community.general/issues?q=is%3Aissue+parted)

Comment: Hmm ok, let me open a ticket in the provided link. Probably we will get some suggestions over there. Thanks for all your help. Really appreciate it.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue related to parted module. What is the solution?